# Weird bug with AlpingJS and Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have the following simple table with Livewire:

```
@foreach ($sms_lists as $sms_list)
    <x-table.row>
        @if($listForEdit && $listForEdit['id'] == $sms_list->id)
        <x-table.cell>
            <span wire:click="firstAction">FIRST</span>
            <span wire:click="secondAction">SECOND</span>
        </x-table.cell>
        @else
        <x-table.cell>
            <span wire:click="thirdAction">THIRD</span>
            <span wire:click="fourthAction">FOURTH</span>
        </x-table.cell>
        @endif
    </x-table.row>
@endforeach
```

NOTE: For the problem described below I have tested in this environment mostly with `button`, but also with `a` and `div`. I have made it `span` just for clarity.

The `SECOND` item always performs `fourthAction`.
If I comment out the `FOURTH` item, `SECOND` starts working.

If I change to the fourth item just to `<span></span>` or **ANY** element - `SECOND` stops working.

It works only if the `@else` has only one `span`. I see the icon and text of `SECOND` but somehow all attributes are from `FOURTH`... including all events and `onclicks` etc.

*PS*: Adding an ID to the FOURTH makes it stay persistently and never hide, even if it's whole block is hidden in the `@else`, it just stays between the FIRST and SECOND...

Comment: this is all blade code???

Comment: Yes, this is a blade.php component serviced by Livewire. The `x-` components all contain a simple HTML structure and nothing else.

Comment: the code inside the blade component must be into div container

Answer (score 1):

You've to add `wire:key="$loop->index"` to the row for livewire to identify the rows.